# While uploading opencart website from local host to my server getting these errors:

Tags: opencart

> Notice: Use of undefined constant DIR_SYSTEM - assumed 'DIR_SYSTEM' in /home/classifi/public_html/maginn/system/startup.php on line 77  Warning: require_once(DIR_SYSTEMhelper/json.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/classifi/public_html/maginn/system/startup.php on line 77  Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'DIR_SYSTEMhelper/json.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in /home/classifi/public_html/maginn/system/startup.php on line 77  Fatal error: Class 'Registry' not found in /home/classifi/public_html/maginn/index.php on line 35

Comment: It seems to be broken.

Comment: [This change](https://github.com/abantecart/abantecart-src/commit/c2fec421c30468e651826ea0d2de1a5d6640e9be) might address your problem, according to [this post](http://forum.abantecart.com/index.php/topic,213.msg628.html?AC_SESSID=i81t4gja76me801k8cqeae2es2#msg628).